# Unexpected UIView offset in UIViewController hierarchy with container controllers and UINavigationController

Tags: ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UINavigationController with a number of child view controllers, some of which are container controllers. The UIView frame layout of the last added child UIViewController (green background) has its parent background (yellow) through when it should not.

[image]

How can I layout everything so all of the views fit within the bounds of the screen below the Navigation bar without the weird offset?

UIViewController hierarchy, started in my AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationController rootViewController:FrontFacadeViewController < UIViewController
    view (0,0) dim:(320x460)

    => StandardCoverViewController < UIViewController
    added as addSubview of FrontFacadeViewController's view]    
    view: (0,0) dim:(320x460)       

        => ConfigurationViewController < UIViewController
        added by pushing onto self.navigationController
        view: (0,20) (320x460)

            => GearViewController < UIViewController
            added as subview of ConfigurationViewController's view 
            view: (0,0) (320x416)
```

Here's how all of the view controllers are created:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    FrontFacadeViewController *frontController = [[FrontFacadeViewController alloc]
        initWithBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    _appNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
        initWithRootViewController:frontController];        
}
```

FrontFacadeViewController:

```
// FrontFacadeViewController determines a particular view controller to present 
// based on some business logic.
// Because of this, it adds child UIViewControllers using container controllers.
//
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    StandardCoverViewController *controller = [StandardCoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:self.nibBundle];

    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];    
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];    
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];    
}

- (IBAction)onButtonPress {
    ConfigurationViewController *controller = [[ConfigurationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:self.nibBundle];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];        
}
```

ConfigurationViewController: (yellow background)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    GearViewController *controller = [[GearViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:self.nibBundle];
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];    
}
```

GearViewController: (green background)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    // nothing special
}
```

Am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: did happen with me but I don't remember what I did to fix it =(

Comment: If you remember, that would be helpful.